# PHP: When does a global variable get removed from memory

Tags: php, collections, memory-leaks, global, garbage

My intention is to know that if a global variable can cause memory leaks.
In my script I am declaring a resource as global variable. I kind of know that it should get destructed when the script ends. 
But is there a way a global variable can cause memory leak and affect the HTTP server (say Apache) in the long run of application (if I do not unset my variable from $GLOBALS ) ?

Thanks,
Aravind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global vars in PHP die when the script ends. Very short life ;)